# How to ignore ssl on the microprofile rest client of quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I'd like to ignore hostname verify and ignore client side certification validation while calling https rest api with RestClient

I cannot find a way to do it without using builder.

and seems that the hostverifier does not work at all.

```
public interface RHPAMRestClient {

  // Starts a new process instance of a specified process.
  @POST
  @Path("/server/containers/{containerId}/processes/{processId}/instances")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Object startProcess(@PathParam String containerId, @PathParam String processId, Object req);
}

RHPAMRestClient c = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .baseUri(new URI(""))
    .sslContext(SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true).build())
    .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> { 
        System.err.println("hostname verifier");
        return true;
    })
    .build(RHPAMRestClient.class);

    c.startProcess("", "", null);
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I can only apply custom sslContext from 
`HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a missconfiguration in Quarkus.
According to the documents, https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl, ssl support should be enabled when using quarkus-rest-client and the property `quarkus.ssl.native` should be `true`.

But it seems that it is `false`, this causes the `org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.client.RestClientBuilderImpl` to override your settings

```
if (!SSL_ENABLED) {
            resteasyClientBuilder.httpEngine((new URLConnectionClientEngineBuilder()).resteasyClientBuilder(resteasyClientBuilder).build());
            resteasyClientBuilder.sslContext((SSLContext)null);
            resteasyClientBuilder.trustStore((KeyStore)null);
            resteasyClientBuilder.keyStore((KeyStore)null, "");
        }
```

Forcing the property to true will magically make everything work as expected.
So, just set

`quarkus.ssl.native=true` in your `application.properties` file

(using Quarkus 1.3.1.Final)

Comment: I was running in this issue also. You need to set the property to true to make ssl work

Thanks